# Unable to create ADO.NET Entity Data Model Code First from database for SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio, sqlite

I installed (from [SQLite's site](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)) `Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.5.1) sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.94.0.exe` as it says *This is the only setup package that is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2013*. I installed it making sure that it installed everything into Visual Studio and all GAC DLL references.

I made sure I had the latest x86 [Visual C++ Runtime Library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784).

I added all installed SQLite DLLs into my project as references from the GAC.

I made sure my project had only x86 as its target, and that my whole solution was targeting x86, and .NET Framework 4.5.1.

I made sure my project included EntityFramework from nuget packages.

I even tried to follow [this video](http://vimeo.com/103372740) to perfection.

I've searched on Stack and tried anything I could find, but **still**, whenever I try to add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my project, select "Code First from database", hit Next, I **do not** see SQLite under the options for **Which data connection should your application use to connect to the database?** In fact, there is absolutely no selection option here. What's the problem here?

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, Update 4 on Windows 8.1 Pro x64. Is this a running bug with SQLite? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a well known issue, yes. Could you try to install the latest (beta) tools http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44234 which include this fix https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2506

Comment: @ErikEJ Yup, give me a second :)

Comment: @ErikEJ Nope, still the same thing.

Comment: Did you install the Sqlite.ef6 package and are all required config setting present and correct in the config file of your .exe project?